# Monitor directory for new files only

Tags: c, linux, monitoring, solaris, filesystems

I'd like to monitor a directory for new files from a C app. However, I'm not interested in modified files, only in new files. Currently I'm using readdir/stat for that purpose:

```
while ( (ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL ) {
  strcpy(path, mon_dir);
  strcat(path, "/");
  strcat(path, ent->d_name);
  if ( stat(path, &statbuf) == -1 ) {
    printf( "Can't stat %s\n", ent->d_name );
    continue;
  }
  if ( S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode) ) {
    if ( statbuf.st_mtime > *timestamp ) {
      tcomp = localtime( &statbuf.st_mtime );
      strftime( s_date, sizeof(s_date), "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tcomp );
      printf( "%s %s was added\n", s_date, ent->d_name );
      *timestamp = statbuf.st_mtime;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can detect newly created files on **Linux AND Solaris 10** without keeping a list of files?

Cheers,

Martin.

Comment: C# has event handlers for change of directory status. That is, if newly files created inside directory. This possibly relies on some kind of Win API which was probably developed using C. This comment isn't an exact answer, but I anticipate that something OS related may exist.

Comment: Please tell for what platform(s) are you planing to deploy.

Comment: since you have said in a comment that you are targeting Linux and Solaris, I have taken the liberty of adding those two tags.

Comment: @JeremyP: Thanks. I've also updated the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to store the last access time in a global variable and pick the latest files with a filter to `scandir()`:

`int cmp_mtime( const struct dirent** lentry, const struct dirent** rentry )`:

1. Stat `(*lentry)->d_name` (extended by path, but that's a detail only)
2. `ltime = statbuf.st_mtime;`
3. Stat `(*rentry)->d_name` (extended by path, but that's a detail only)
4. `rtime = statbuf.st_mtime;`
5. `if ( ltime < rtime ) return -1;`
6. `else if ( ltime > rtime ) return 1;`
7. `return 0;`

`int selector( const struct dirent* entry )`:

1. Stat `entry->d_name` (extended by path, but that's a detail only)
2. If not normal file then return 0
3. If `stat.st_mtime > lastseen` then return 1 else return 0

Main:

1. Init global time variable `lastseen`
2. `scandir( directory, &entries, selector, cmp_mtime );`
3. Process list of entries
4. lastseen := mtime of last entry in list

Comment: Can you please provide me the full implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that code with me. It belongs to my former company. But you should be able to derive the information if you check the scandir() manual and consider what I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will re-check it.

Answer (score 7):

[gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/) provides an abstraction around system dependant file notification apis for many *nixes , and it's included in many linux distros by default.

For linux, you could use the linux specific [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) api.

Win32 has a similar API via [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Is gamin available as Solaris 10 package? If so, I could consider it.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no better way with Solaris 10 outside interfacing with either the dtrace command or libdtrace (not recommended). On SunOS 5.11 based OSes (eg: OpenSolaris, Solaris 11 Express, ...), you can just use the [File Event Notification framework](http://blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification).

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS X there is a [file monitoring API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html) and the provided sample code shows how to find which files have changed.

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm targeting Linux/Solaris only. But thanks for the link anyways.

Answer (score 0):

one trick may be to set the archive bit for handled files.

Edith says:
if nothing else from the other answeres helpes, you may play with chmod() instead.

Comment: Nice idea (+1). However, I'm targeting Solaris/Linux where there is no archive bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FAM - File Alteration Monitor](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fam/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Was researching the same topic on Solaris and found the example of the `watchdir` app, to be used from within scripts, as in

```
watchdir /foo/bar
```

which will perform a blocking wait until something happens on the watched directory.

Link: https://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/solaris-file-event-notification/

Answer (score 0):

I know you were asking for a solution from C but in fact Java (now) has a cross-platform class for this.  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). Also see documentation for the [WatchService class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) which is the central class of Java's file change notification ability.

Perhaps there's some documentation somewhere as to how Java accomplishes this on the various platforms ?

From the little I understand Java uses the OS's native file change notification API on Linux, Solaris and Windows and then in addition also implements a fallback method which is based on polling and which will work on any platform.