# access() with blocking option in C

Tags: c

I've just recently learned how to check if a file exists, in C, without opening it with open(). What I wanted to ask is if there is an option or a flag or other instruction that checks if a file exists, but blocks the process until the file exists. Something like this:

```
    while(access("socket", F_OK) !=0);
```

But without all this processing cycle... Something like select but to check if a file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this portably, and on some filesystems (e.g. certain network filesystems) there simply isn't any way to do it at all without periodically checking for the file's existence.

That said, there are *nonportable* approaches which can cover the majority of platforms in wide use:

- OS X: [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html)
- Linux: [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)
- *BSD: [kqueue](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)
- Windows: [ReadDirectoryChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the approaches and for the answer. I now have some readings to do!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard function that does what you're asking for.

The way you're checking is poor form in that it will consume as much CPU time as it possibly can while checking. At a minimum, you want to add a delay in your loop, such as:

`while(access("socket", F_OK) !=0) sleep(1);`

A better solution is to monitor a directory for changes. There isn't any standard function to do this but there are various operating system specific methods. See [Monitor directory for new files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097429/monitor-directory-for-new-files-only) for some possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I though about this approach but the socket I wanted to check if created takes much less time than a second to be created so would be some wasted time instead of wasted cpu. Thank you for the monitor directory. Will check thoose possibilities