# iterating through a directory that is constantly being updated in C

Tags: c, loops, directory

I'm looking for a method by which I can iterate through a directory that will have files added to it (say every 20 seconds) and perform an action (in this case computing a hash).
The issue is that I can't work out a method that will only perform this action on newly added files; instead repeating the action unnecessarily on older files.

I'm very new to C programming, and I appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097429/monitor-directory-for-new-files-only

Answer (score 0):

There is no platform-neutral way of doing this, as far as I know.

On POSIX, you can use [`opendir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and friends, perhaps running it periodically and manually checking for new files between each run. Doable, but a lot of work.

On Linux, you can use the [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) API to get notifications from the kernel when a certain directory changes, this is more efficient but less portable. Win32 as similar support, no idea about Macs but I'm sure there's something.